# Using ~/.fonts.conf to change the weight of monospace fonts

Tags: fonts

On OS X, monospaced fonts are slightly more weighted than the other fonts. This (I feel) helps bring out the colors more vividly. [image: screenshot]

Since I am on Linux, I'm trying to replicate the behavior. I'm trying to do this by editing the property "weight" in `~/.fonts.conf`,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <test name="family">
      <string>DejaVu Sans Mono</string>
      <string>Bitstream Vera Sans Mono</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="weight" mode="assign">
        <const>medium</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Apparently, this does not work properly. What happens is that bold face DejaVu or Bitstream mono fonts becomes more bold, and nothing happens to the other.
[image: screenshot]

So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out. From the man page of `fonts-conf`, the property `weight` sets the weight of the bold face, and *not the weight of the font*. This was why changing `weight` lead to a bolder boldface rather than change the whole font. What I was looking for was `emboldening` which enables synthetic font emboldening. Using that in `~/.fonts.conf` solved the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<match target="font">
    <test name="family">
    <string>Inconsolata</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="embolden" mode="assign">
        <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

Before and after using Inconsolata 12 pt. font (I also disabled font hinting while taking this screenshot).

[image: before screenshot]

[image: after screenshot]

It would be nice if the amount of emboldening could also be controlled.

Comment: I would also love to figure out how to control the weight of the emboldening. Maybe half-embolden would be closest to Mac OS X style.